# Slow speed between mounts on same shared disk

Tags: linux, mount, cifs

how i could fix problem with moving speed between two mounts of shared windows disk. CIFS/SMB share.

i.e.
i have shared disk //disk1 and mounted folders inside it on linux system

```
//disk1/folder1 /mnt/folder1
                         subfolder1
                         subfolder2
//disk1/folder2 /mnt/folder2
                         subfolder1
                         subfolder2
```

if i'm moving files inside folder1 between subfolders it moves files instantly.
if i'm moving files from /mnt/folder1 to /mnt/folder2 speed drastically drops.

Sincerely, D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, because now the data has to be transferred to the client and then back to the server instead of just moved on the server. This is inherent when you have multiple shares.

To fix this, create a share that includes both `folder1` and `folder2`.